# The type or namespace name could not be found with .NET Core Fakes and VS 2019 Preview 6.9.0 Preview 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

**Update 2**

I fixed the problem in Update 1, but the similar code below doesn't work, and has the same error.

The sample is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019#get-started-with-shims

**Target code**

```
  public class DateShimDemo
    {
        public int GetTheCurrentYear()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.Year;
        }
    }
```

**Test code:**

```
[TestClass]
    public class DateShimDemoTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestCurrentYear()
        {
            int fixedYear = 2000;

            // Shims can be used only in a ShimsContext:
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                // Arrange:
                // Shim DateTime.Now to return a fixed date:
                System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet  
   //The type or namespace name 'Fakes' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
                   = () =>   
                    { return new DateTime(fixedYear, 1, 1); };

                // Instantiate the component under test:
                var componentUnderTest = new DateShimDemo();

                // Act:
                int year = componentUnderTest.GetTheCurrentYear();

                // Assert:
                // This will always be true if the component is working:
                Assert.AreEqual(fixedYear, year);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

I followed the sample below,

https://medium.com/@ckellywilson/visual-studio-2019-and-net-core-fakes-fea47caccdc8

**Target code**

```
 public class SampleUserSecurity
    {
        public SampleUserSecurity()
        {
        }

        public SampleUserSecurity(string domain, string username, string password)
        {
            this.UserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password));
        }

        public UserPrincipal UserPrincipal { get; set; }

        public bool IsAccountLocked()
        {
            return this.UserPrincipal.IsAccountLockedOut();
        }
    }
```

**Test code:**

```
[TestClass]
    public class SampleUserSecurityTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                var target = new SampleUserSecurity();

                var shimUserPrincipal = new ShimUserPrincipal();  //error here
                var shimAuthtenticatedPrincipal = new ShimAuthenticablePrincipal(shimUserPrincipal) { IsAccountLockedOut = () => false };
                target.UserPrincipal = shimUserPrincipal;

                bool isLocked = false;
                bool testIsLocked = target.IsAccountLocked();

                Assert.Equal(isLocked, testIsLocked);
            }
        }
    }
```

But an error below occurred

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ShimUserPrincipal' could not
> be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any idea?

**Refs**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019

**Update**
Thanks @magicandre1981 for pointing it out.

Comment: you miss using statement so use full statement: **var userPrincipal = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Fakes.ShimUserPrincipal();**

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: can you see Update 2 please?

Comment: I posted an answer, it is too long for a comment

Comment: and have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials you follow are for .net framework. For [.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2019#transitioning-your-net-framework-test-projects-that-use-microsoft-fakes-to-sdk-style-net-framework-or-net-core-projects) you have to select `System.Runtime` (not System) and select "Add Fakes Assembly"

[image]

Check the page [APIsof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/ba1e6bdf-6174-3b81-0419-a7c98ebf1383?fx=netcoreapp3.1) which assembly includes a class in .net core.

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried this. But I marked it answered. Please correct it if it is not working.